# Word for "considered but not used"?

Tags: word-choice

What is a good word that captures the concept of being considered, but not used?

For example:

"The scientists considered the implications of Charlie's proposed solution, but in the end tossed it in the bin with the other _____ ideas."

Comment: Could it be as simple as *rejected*?

Comment: IMO "rejected" is the right choice @WS2. I'd add it as an answer if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically **rejected** works.

If there is a reason then:

- infeasible
- impractical
- impossible
- unconscionable

Comment: *unaccepted* can be used either

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer **rejected** may be appropriate, it subtly implies that there was something wrong or undesirable about the idea. e.g., "the proposal was rejected because it was incomplete."

If a more neutral word is desired, **dismissed** may work.